# How to run mstest unit tests in visual studio 2015 in sequence?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

I want to know how I can run mstest unit tests in visual studio 2015 in sequence?

Is there any configuration I can do?

Comment: When you say "in sequence" do you mean in a specific order or just serially with non parallelization?

Comment: @JohnKoerner just serially with non parallelization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests are run sequentially by default. No additional configuration is necessary.

Comment: Does that mean second test will start after end of first test case?

Comment: Yes. By default, they will run one after the other. The order of execution is not guranteed, though.